# Is there a finite set of polynomials generating all rational numbers by iteration?

Tags: real-analysis, continued-fractions, continuity, rational-functions

In [this previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/412923/7113) I asked for the smallest set of continuous real functions that could generate $\mathbb{Q}$ by iteration starting from 0. Surprisingly one continuous function suffices.

The function constructed though is by necessity complex and certainly not elementary. I think it would be interesting to know if an example exists with simpler functions. Hence the following question:

> Does there exist a finite set of polynomials whose iterates generate $\mathbb{Q}$?

I'm not certain of the answer to this even for linear polynomials. For example $x/2+1$, $x/2-1$ and $2x$ gets you close by generating all non-repeating binary fractions, a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. However it seems impossible to extend this to obtain all of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: There are only finitely many primes dividing the denominators of the coefficients. So you will stay in the ring generated by the inverses of these primes.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think you are right - too easy - I should have realised that! Add this as an answer which I will accept if you like.